# Programmatically hide columns in GridComponent with Kendo UI for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to set columns in GridComponent as hidden programmatically with Kendo UI for Angular, but can't find any function or property other than the [hidden] property on the component html element.

It's the same functionality as when you check a column as visible/hidden in the column menu I'm looking for.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this not helpful https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/hidden/?

Comment: That example breaks when using [columnMenu]="true". I still want the menu option to be available.

Answer (score 3):

I have edited the example of this [hide column](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/hidden/), column menu is working and column is hiding as well

Example URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2rip3?file=app/app.component.ts

you can visit here to see update example https://gvfum8.run.stackblitz.io and code for this example

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" style="height:400px" [columnMenu]="true">
          <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
            <kendo-grid-column
              field="{{column}}"
              [hidden]="hiddenColumns.indexOf(column) > -1"
            >
              <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-dataItem>
                  {{dataItem.field}}
              </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public gridData: any[] = sampleCustomers;

    public columns: string[] = [
      'CompanyName', 'ContactName', 'ContactTitle'
    ];

    public hiddenColumns: string[] = [];

    public restoreColumns(): void {
        this.hiddenColumns = [];
    }

    constructor(){
      this.hiddenColumns.push("CompanyName");
    }
}
```

There are three columns, 1st column is hidden and showing two columns.

Comment: works very well. was looking for similar kind of fix and this code helped a lot. Thanks @ali-shahbaz

Comment: @ali-shahbaz If i have kendoGridCellTemplate for every column different template using different pipe how can i set that too with this solution